# How to use variable (datatable) in sql command text to execute

Tags: sql, angularjs, datatable, vertica

I am new to Vertica and trying this in angular aspx page.

```
           `con.Open();
            cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new VerticaParameter("@tblCustomers", table));
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into customers select * from @tblCustomers";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`
```

I have established the connection and inserted some fresh records too.
But Now I am trying to insert bulk records in my vertica database's table.

Something Same like SqlServer,

I have loaded my table data into "table" variable. Which is a datatable.

Is it possible to do like this ?? As I am getting some error

"
`Incorrect syntax at or near $1`"

customers and @tblCustomers both have same columns.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Setting aside whether or not you should do something like this, in the code that you've posted you're passing @tblCustomers as a parameter to the query, so it's going to treat it as a string value, not an object name in the query. You need to build the `CommandText` in your code without that as a parameter. Something like:

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into customers select * from " & tableName
```

(Sorry if that syntax isn't quite right, but hopefully it gets across the point)

Some additional (and important) notes though:

1. Always use a column list when doing an `INSERT`. Use `INSERT INTO MyTable (some_column, some_other_column) SELECT...` not `INSERT INTO MyTable SELECT...`
2. NEVER use `SELECT *`. List out your column names.

Comment: Thanks for your reply !! I will try it

Comment: Using `&` is not correct as I searched it. Not getting what to use

Comment: It looks like the string concatenation operator for angularjs is simply `+`, so try switching it to that. If that works then please let me know and I'll update my answer. I don't have a machine to test it on myself here.

Comment: No, Its not working. Variable table contains multiple rows. Is it possible to use it here ?

Comment: I don't believe so. You'll l likely have to loop through the contents of the variable and insert the items that way. I assumed it was a table name. If you update your question with more complete code (what values @tblCustomer has, etc.) then maybe someone else can help.